# Scrape a table from a website and store as pandas

Tags: python, pandas, http, web-scraping, urllib

In Python, I want to scrape the table in a website(it's a Japanese option trading information), and store it as a pandas dataframe.

The website is [here](https://www.jpx.co.jp/english/markets/index.html), and you need to click "Options Quotes" in order to access the page where I want to scrape the table. The final URL is https://svc.qri.jp/jpx/english/nkopm/ but you cannot directly access this page.

Here is my attempt:

```
pd.read_html("https://svc.qri.jp/jpx/english/nkopm/")
...HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

So I thought I need to add a user agent. Here is my another attempt:

```
url = "https://svc.qri.jp/jpx/english/nkopm/"
pd.read_html(requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text)
...ValueError: No tables found
```

Another attempt

```
import urllib
url = 'https://svc.qri.jp/jpx/english/nkopm/'
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(url)
tables = pd.read_html(response.read(), attrs={"class":"price-table"})[0]
...HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I know how to play with pandas, so it doesn't have to be imported in a neat dataframe at first place. I just need to first import the table in pandas, but I'm not sure why I cannot even read the page. Any help would be appreciated!

By the way, if you click gray arrows in the middle column, [image],

it will add another row like this.
[image]

And it can be all opened and closed by clicking these buttons.
[image]

It would be nice if I can import these rows as well, but it not really a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation of the pandas function `read_html` it says

> Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.

So the function expects structured input in form of an html table. I actually can't access the website you're linking to but I'm guessing it will give you back an entire website.

You need to extract the data in a structured format in order for pandas to make sense of it. You need to scrape it. There's a bunch of tools for that, and one popular one is [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Tl;dr: So what you need to do is download the website with `requests`, pass it into `BeautifulSoup` and then use `BeautifulSoup` to extract the data in a structured format.

---

Updated answer:

Seems like the reason why the requests is returning a `400` is because the website is expecting some additional headers - I just dumped the request my browser does into requests and it works!

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://www.jpx.co.jp/english/markets/index.html',
    'Accept-Language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,it;q=0.6,la;q=0.5',
}

response = requests.get('https://svc.qri.jp/jpx/english/nkopm/', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited the question so that you can access the webpage. You need to open the link and go to "Options Quotes".

Comment: Oh I needed to give this many attributes. thank you, i have the table in pandas now :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Ahmad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333975/ahmad) answer, you're almost there:

All you need to get the table is this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://www.jpx.co.jp/english/markets/index.html',
    'Accept-Language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,it;q=0.6,la;q=0.5',
}

response = requests.get('https://svc.qri.jp/jpx/english/nkopm/', headers=headers)
table = pd.read_html(response.text, attrs={"class": "price-table"})[0]
print(table)
```

This outputs:

```
                                                  CALL  ...                                                PUT
                                       Settlement09/18  ...                                    Settlement09/18
0                                                    2  ...                                               3030
1    Delta  Gamma  Theta  Vega  0.0032  0.0000  -0....  ...              Delta  Gamma  Theta  Vega  -  -  -  -
2                                                Delta  ...                                                NaN
3                                               0.0032  ...                                                NaN
4                                                Delta  ...                                                NaN
..                                                 ...  ...                                                ...
```